# .clang_complete and CMake?

Tags: cmake, clang-complete

I'm using CMake to genenerate my Makefile's however I cannot generate the .clang_complete using the standard

```
make CC='~/.vim/bin/cc_args.py gcc' CXX='~/.vim/bin/cc_args.py g++' -B
```

nothing gets generated...

the tree structure looks like so

```
Root
 |
 |_core
 |  |_src
 |  |  |_main.cpp
 |  |  |_CMakeLists.txt (1)
 |  |_inc
 |  |_CMakeLists.txt (2)
 |
 |_lib
 |  |_rtaudio
 |
 |_CMakeLists.txt (3)
```

CMakeLists.txt (1) file:

```
 include_directories("${Dunkel_SOURCE_DIR}/core/inc")

include_directories("${Dunkel_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/")
link_directories("${Dunkel_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/rtaudio")

add_executable(Dunkel main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Dunkel rtaudio)
```

CMakeLists.txt (2) file:

```
subdirs(src)
```

CMakeLists.txt (3) file:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)

PROJECT(Dunkel)
SUBDIRS(core)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g")
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is `make ...` a typo? You need to run `CC=gcc CXX=g++ cmake /path/to/src`. What is in these python scripts `~/.vim/bin/cc_args.py`?

Comment: cc_args wraps calls to the compiler pointed to by CC CXX variables. it processes each call and outputs any external depdencies to a config file called .clang_complete so when clang_complete is looking for the source files etc of some external lib it knows where to look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like contrary to `make` `cmake` doesn't expand tilde, hence it treats is as part of the path. To make it work as expected either use absolute path to the `cc_args.py` script or do two simple changes in the command:

1. Replace the tilde with `$HOME`.
2. Replace single quotes with double quotes.

After the changes your command should look like this:

```
CXX="$HOME/.vim/bin/cc_args.py g++" cmake ..
```

And it should work.

Comment: I just tried this on OS X 10.9.5 with cmake 3.0.2 and had to provide the full user path. $HOME is correctly set, but it appears that it is not getting expanded

Comment: @thisisdog, it depends on the shell you use. `CXX=~/...` might work instead, `CXX="$HOME/..."` works fine in bash.

Comment: Please see my answer, I tried to follow your advice, but perhaps `CXX` is not the correct variable to use (at least for me), because nothing related to "cc_args" is coming out of cmake...

Answer (score 2):

You should run (in your build directory)

```
CXX='~/.vim/bin/cc_args.py g++' cmake ..
```

and then run `make` as usual. Note that this will run the cc_args.py script every time you build the project with `make`, if you want to disable this, re-run `cmake` again.

The file `.clang_complete` will be created in the build directory, move it if needed.

See also [Vim: Creating .clang_complete using CMake](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2013/01/29/vim-creating-clang_complete-using-cmake/)

Comment: problem is with this approach i get  
"Could not find compiler set in environment variable CXX:

  ~/.vim/bin/cc_args.py clang++.

Comment: Sounds like your cc_args.py doesn't resides in `~/.vim/bin/cc_args.py`

Comment: it does... 
pepe@ppp:~/.vim/bin$ ls -l
total 12
-rwxrwxrw- 1 pepe pepe 1816 Jan 26 01:15 cc_args.py

Answer (score 1):

It is important to use `$HOME/.vim/bin/cc_args.py` and not `~/.vim/bin/cc_args.py`, because `~` might not get expanded when quoted.

Also, verify the presence of the python script with:

```
$ ls -l $HOME/.vim/bin/cc_args.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 myself  staff  2270 Sep 19 16:11 /home/myself/.vim/bin/cc_args.py
```

if not found, adjust the python script path as necessary.

<strike>Run `make clean` in the build dir.</strike>

As suggested by @xaizek, **start with an empty build directory** (assuming the build directory is a subdir of the source dir):

```
CXX="$HOME/.vim/bin/cc_args.py g++" cmake ..
```

followed by:

```
make
```

at this point, make will be building the project, but calling `cc_args.py` (which will call `g++`), instead of directly calling `g++`.

<strike>However this part for me is failing to work, and no `.clang_complete` file is created in the build directory or anywhere else.</strike>

In fact, there is no occurrence of "cc_args" in the generated CMakeCache.txt / Makefile, so I suspect `CXX` is not the correct variable name to pass to cmake.

**When finished, copy `.clang_complete` to the parent dir.**

Comment: Inadequate quirks of cmake are everywhere... See their [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/envvar/CXX.html). You need to remove `CMakeCache.txt` yourself if it's left from previous build or `$CXX` won't be respected. I don't see a documented way to specify compiler command with an argument via `-D` parameters.... (this seems to work though `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=".../cc_args.py" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ARG1=g++`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me

```
sudo chmod a+x $HOME/.vim/bin/cc_args.py
CXX="$HOME/.vim/bin/cc_args.py  g++"  sudo cmake ..
sudo make
```

and then ls -a shows my .clang_complete file but still emtyp though.